# is there any way to take processing canvas context and put it in database

Tags: javascript, php, processing

My qestion is, Is there any way that i can take array of processing objects from canvas and put it in the database and add for each object ID and it's position in the array?

Answer (score 0):

Just store your state in a data structure that lends itself to being stored in a database.

For example, if you're going to draw a bunch of circles to the canvas, just create a `Circle` class that contains everything you need to know to draw a circle. Use that class to draw your frames:

```
ArrayList<Circle> circles = new ArrayList<Circle>();

void setup() {
  size(500, 500);
  for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
    circles.add(new Circle());
  }
}

void draw() {
  background(0);
  for (Circle c : circles) {
    c.draw();
  }
}

class Circle {
  float x;
  float y;
  float r;
  color c;

  public Circle() {
    x = random(width);
    y = random(height);
    r = random(10, 100);
    c = color(random(255), random(255), random(255));
  }

  void draw() {
    fill(c);
    ellipse(x, y, r, r);
  }
}
```

Now that you have that, you can store instances of your `Circle` class in a database however you want. You could convert them to JSON and then store that in a database, or you could convert them to rows and columns, or you could use something like Hibernate.

Comment: I got the array of objects but i am not shore how to make the JSON requests and i am not shore how to interact with them can you give me link somewhere to see some kind of example?

Comment: @MimiChan That question is much too broad. There are a bunch of ways to convert an object to JSON. You could just build the String yourself. And how you insert it into the database depends on the database you're using. Try splitting your problem up into smaller pieces. Can you write a simple sketch that simply converts an object to json and prints it to the console? Can you create a separate sketch that stores a hard-coded String to a database? Go from there, and try to ask more specific questions if you get stuck.

Comment: thank you i am just asking for that some guidance because i don't know from where to begin i'll try to do these things and if i stuck i'll ask.